# Should I always create classes that have both attributes and methods?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, software-design

Is it considered a bad practice? If it's not always a bad practice, when is it appropriate to create classes without attributes or methods?

Comment: @jaco0646 You're right, the description was confusing. I have improved it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary for a class to contain methods as well as attributes. Suppose a secenerio in which some attributes are publicly defined for the meantime use so we can use this variable from anywhere outside the class. But to use encapsulation it is recommended to attributes to be private.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean **always**, my answer is no, you shouldn't always do that.

If the language allows you to do so, there must be a reason. Consider the following factory class:

```
public class Factory : IFactory
{
    public const string FactoryName = "StackOverflowFactory";

    public IPerson GetPerson(PersonType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case PersonType.Rural:
                return new Villager();
            case PersonType.Urban:
                return new CityPerson();
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("{0} does not handle {1}", FactoryName, type));
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, a class contains an attribute and a method. And this is normal.

On the other hand, when we're talking about something like [passive data structure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure), the objects and classes that are created to fulfill this kind of purpose, then you should not mix the attributes with the methods because the purpose of those objects is to store data, not manipulate it.

The **Good** or **Bad** is always relative, base on how the system is designed, the purpose of the classes, etc. If the system is designed using a pattern A but you violate that pattern when changing the code, then that *may* be a bad practice. If the class is just for storing data but you add some methods to manipulate it, then that *may* also be a bad practice too.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of a passive data structure?

Comment: And an example of a class with methods but no attribute?

Comment: @Thomas in general a **binding model** in .NET MVC is a plain object and without any methods.

Comment: @Thomas imagine that you want to have a class which contains a method to return the biggest number in a list (yes, just like the **Math.max**). In this case your class will just have a (static) method and no attributes.